# var_dump $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] shows expected string, but unexpected result when comparing or parsing

Tags: php, var-dump

I have a strange problem. Someone has created a url similar to my website ([www.greatwebsite.com](http://www.greatwebsite.com)) and has been scraping the content in real time to show on their website ([www.bestwebsite.com](http://www.bestwebsite.com)) (I have changed URLs for my client's privacy). I have been trying to redirect requests made through this bad actor url, but have not been able to as the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable has the wrong value in it....

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
var_dump($host);
?>
```

When I visit the official website at [www.greatwebsite.com](http://www.greatwebsite.com) the HTTP_HOST variable outputs string(20) "www.greatwebsite.com" as it should and when I compare the string value to "www.greatwebsite.com" everything works properly.

However, when I visit the bad actor website at [www.bestwebsite.com](http://www.bestwebsite.com) the var_dump outputs
string(20) "www.bestwebsite.com" but the character count is 20 instead of 19. If I try to compare the string to "www.bestwebsite.com" it returns false. So I then printed out each character in the string and even though var_dump shows [www.bestwebsite.com](http://www.bestwebsite.com) the string inside actually is [www.greatwebsite.com](http://www.greatwebsite.com). If I echo the contents of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] it shows [www.bestwebsite.com](http://www.bestwebsite.com) so I tried to capture it via output buffering like this

```
ob_start();
echo $host;
$output = ob_get_clean(); 
ob_end_clean();

echo $output; //outputs www.bestwebsite.com
echo substr($output, 4, 4); //outputs great
```

echo stills shows [www.bestwebsite.com](http://www.bestwebsite.com), but when I compare what is in $output it still acts as if the value is [www.greatwebsite.com](http://www.greatwebsite.com) so I am unable to write logic to detect when the request is coming from the bad actor website.

Does anyone know why the HTTP_HOST value is doing this and how I can compare the value successfully to determine if the request is coming from this bad actor website so I can redirect it somewhere else so they will stop stealing my client's content?

Comment: Using HTTP_HOST is generally a bad idea for this kind of logic as it can be spoofed quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem in informatics - the boundary between "always zero" and "one or more". Once it is possible to have at least 1 bad actor - it is very possible to have many more. If you try to protect by blacklisting each bad actor - you will exhaust your resources. A better strategy is to use a whitelist - i.e. if the HTTP_HOST is not `www.greatwebsite.com` then do not serve any content at all. This can be achieved by a simple `header('HTTP/1.1 444 Go home', TRUE, 444)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the contents of HTTP_HOST when compared is always www.greatwebsite.com even when it's coming from www.bestwebsite.com. I am really confused as to how it's possible that HTTP_HOST shows www.bestwebsite.com in var_dump but the value when compared is www.greatwebsite.com.

Comment: HTTP_HOST can not be anything else than `www.greatwebsite.com` or otherwise your web server will refuse to serve it (unless it has a `catchAll` type of VirtualHost configured to handle all request with unrecognized HTTP_HOST values). So now after your comment it is clear that you're fighting with the source of the request and not with the destination. In that case simply log the IP where such bad requests come and then block the IP(s) in the firewall of the web server.